# Get 100% with rounded percentages of objects values in an array

Tags: arrays, object, ecmascript-6, rounding

I have an array of objects, and a value of the objects is a percent. Is there a way to round those values and still get 100% if added?

```
const items = [
    {
        name: 'Something',
        value: 20.4
    },
    {
        name: 'something else',
        value: 36.6
    },
    {
        name: 'another thing',
        value: 21.5
    },
    {
        name: 'other item',
        value: 21.5
    }
];
```

and return something like this

```
const items = [
    {
        name: 'Something',
        value: 20
    },
    {
        name: 'something else',
        value: 37
    },
    {
        name: 'another thing',
        value: 21
    },
    {
        name: 'other item',
        value: 22
    }
];
```

Comment: You'd have to make your own rounding that takes into account the previous rounding. E.g., if the previous value was rounded down, the next one might need to be rounded up. Or otherwise consider all the fractions you've removed. It's still a problem with, say, `10.2`, `5.1`, `12.2`, `7.2`, `8.3` (etc., all below the `.5` threshold), for example - you'd have to round one of these up even though it's below `.5`. Which means you might skew the results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to achieve this is to iterate over the array, maintaining a rolling sum of the rounded values and then setting the last value in the array to `100 - sum`:

```js
const items = [
  { name: 'Something', value: 20.4 },
  { name: 'something else', value: 36.6 },
  { name: 'another thing', value: 21.5 },
  { name: 'other item', value: 21.5 }
];

let sum = 0;
const rounded = items.map(({name, value}, i) => {
  if (i == items.length - 1) {
    return { name, value: 100 - sum };
  }
  value = Math.round(value);
  sum = sum + value;
  return { name, value };
});

console.log(rounded);
```